# Could not find bootstrapApplication call in apps/product/src/main.ts while adding @angular/material with Nrwl Nx Mfa Workspace

Tags: angular, angular-material, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have created a project with the Nx Mfa schema as follows

```
npx create-nx-workspace fetebird --preset=empty

npm install --save-dev @nrwl/angular

nx g @nrwl/angular:host host --remotes=product,discount,order


nx serve host --open
```

This works. Now I am trying to add angular material to the MFA applicatins with below commands

```
npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add --project=product
```

or

```
npm install @angular/material && npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add // thows an exception as project name not specified
```

While specifying the project name, getting an exceptions as

```
npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add --project=product

>  NX  Generating @angular/material:ng-add

✔ Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: · indigo-pink
✔ Set up global Angular Material typography styles? (y/N) · true
✔ Include the Angular animations module? · enabled
✔ Packages installed successfully.
SchematicsException [Error]: Could not find bootstrapApplication call in apps/product/src/main.ts
    at addModuleImportToStandaloneBootstrap (/Users/san/project/Sample/fetebird/node_modules/@angular/cdk/schematics/utils/ast/standalone.js:40:15)
    at addAnimationsModuleToStandaloneApp (/Users/san/project/Sample/fetebird/node_modules/@angular/material/schematics/ng-add/setup-project.js:83:67)
    at /Users/san/project/Sample/fetebird/node_modules/@angular/material/schematics/ng-add/setup-project.js:61:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 3):

It’s because the ng-add schematic tries to add it to an NgModule app, but if that fails, it then tries to add it to a Standalone app, and then it fails again.

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/schematics/ng-add/setup-project.ts#L67-82

Install the angular material lib

```
npm install @angular/material
```

The issue with Angular Material. They aren't supporting other builders which are required for MFEs.

So manually change your app's executor in the build target to be
@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser, then run the generate command
again for Angular Material

**project.json** For MFE, if `executor` not present in `project.json`, check in `workspace.json`

```
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
```

The run the generator command

```
npx nx g @angular/material:ng-add --project=host

>  NX  Generating @angular/material:ng-add

✔ Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: · indigo-pink
✔ Set up global Angular Material typography styles? (y/N) · true
✔ Include the Angular animations module? · excluded
✔ Packages installed successfully.
[NX] Angular devkit called `writeWorkspace`, this may have had unintended consequences in workspace.json
[NX] Double check workspace.json before proceeding
    Your project is not using the default builders for "test". This means that we cannot add the configured theme to the "test" target.
UPDATE package.json
UPDATE workspace.json
UPDATE apps/host/src/index.html
UPDATE apps/host/src/styles.scss
```

During the process exclude the animation `Include the Angular animations module? · excluded`. You can manually add animation later

Revert back the changes as below in `project.json`

```
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/angular:webpack-browser",
```

Comment: nobody followed up on your answer, I have the same problem, followed your steps and now I have material in the host page. So looks like this works at least to solve original problem. I do have a new problem now after this configuration, i'm not able to import material theming, and also having problems to enable the disabled animations, any help or reference you could give?